# [[Scopes]] not visible within the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

[DOM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVFVF.png)

Does anyone know why the [[Scopes]] is not visible on the DOM?

Used console.dir on a function and expected to see the [[Scopes]] for closures but that is missing.

Thank you!

Comment: Functions have little to do with the DOM. So it's not clear what you're asking.

Comment: Please post the code you used that led to the screenshotted output

Answer (score 0):

What code were you trying to run exactly? I can see the [[Scopes]] when I try to `console.dir()` a function. All three of these work for me

```
console.dir(()=>{})
console.dir(function(){})
function f(){}
console.dir(f)
```

[image: Screenshot of working example in Chrome devtools]